# Использование глобальной переменной в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Есть своя таксономия, в которой выводятся посты. У каждого поста есть custom fields с определенными данными (например, с ценами). В сайдбаре на странице хочу сделать вывод максимальной и минимальной цены, но получается только вывести максимальную из первых 10 постов. Как сделать, чтобы выводилась максимальная и минимальная со всей выборки?

```
<?php $cur_tax_name = single_term_title('', 0); ?>
<?php 
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'    => 10,
            'post_type'     => 'kliniki',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'nazvanie_protseduri',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'mrt-vsego-pozvonochnika'
                )
            )
        );

        $results = new WP_Query($args);
    ?>

    <?php if($results->have_posts()): ?>
    <?php while ($results->have_posts()) : $results->the_post(); ?>
        <?php if( have_rows('prices') ):
            while ( have_rows('prices') ) : the_row();

                $prodedura = get_sub_field('diagnostica');
                $proc_price = get_sub_field('prices');      

                if($prodedura == $cur_tax_name and $proc_price != false) {
                    // Вывод короткой записи поста
                }
            endwhile;
            endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Делать запрос на все посты, а выводить только 10. Покажите ваш код.

Comment: Добавил код в описание

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо делать запрос на все посты, а выводить только 10. Например, так:

```
$cur_tax_name = single_term_title( '', 0 );

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => 'kliniki',
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'nazvanie_protseduri',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'mrt-vsego-pozvonochnika'
        )
    )
);

global $max_price, $min_price;
$max_price = 0;
$min_price = 0;
$post_count = 0;

$results = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $results->have_posts() ):
    while ( $results->have_posts() ) : $results->the_post();
        if ( have_rows( 'prices' ) ):
            while ( have_rows( 'prices' ) ) : the_row();
                $proc_price = get_sub_field( 'prices' );
                $max_price =  max( $proc_price, $max_price );
                $min_price =  min( $proc_price, $min_price );
                if ( 10 > $post_count ) { // выводим только первые 10 записей
                    $prodedura  = get_sub_field( 'diagnostica' );

                    if ( $prodedura == $cur_tax_name and $proc_price != false ) {
                        // Вывод короткой записи поста
                    }
                }
            endwhile;
        endif;
        $post_count++;
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Отлично, поменял немного код, но это как раз то, что нужно было!